# A query/procedure to get procedure dependecies sybase

Tags: sybase

I am searching for a query/proceduer that give me all the dependecies of a procedure (results similar to sp_depends)

example in procedure proc1 , it execute proc2,proc3,
         in procedure proc2 , it execute xproc1, xproc2

so I want my output to be like

```
proc1 -> proc2 -> xproc1 ->xproc2
proc1 -> proc3
```

EDIT:

I have created the below procedure , but the problem about them it gave me the below error

```
------------------------ Execute ------------------------
Maximum stored procedure nesting level exceeded (limit 60). Please use sp_configure to increase the 'max nesting level'.
return status = -6
```

Also the after after limiting the count on the cursor ( If your read carefuly the procedure , youll notice count , so I modified the procedure later to specify how many nest I got to avoide the error and I did avoid it ) the result is missing , I didnt get all the procedure dependency , what I am saying  I am not getting all  the procedure dependencies , I though problem with the procedure after investigating and checking into `syscomments` and selecting in depends `sysdepends` it seems sybase doenst give all the dependency . I dont know. Do you have a way that can help me got all the dependency ?

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.PROC_HIERARCHY
( PROC_PATH VARCHAR(4000) NULL
)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.PROC_DEP_REC
    @PROC_ID        INTEGER,
    @PATH           VARCHAR(4000) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @CURR_ID        INTEGER
    DECLARE @CURR_NAME      VARCHAR(40)
    DECLARE @ROW_COUNT      NUMERIC(12)
    DECLARE @PATH_OUT       VARCHAR(4000)

    -- retrieve the children
    DECLARE CURS CURSOR FOR
    select distinct o2.name, o2.id
    from sysdepends d
        inner join sysobjects o
        on d.id = o.id
        inner join sysobjects o2
        on d.depid = o2.id
    where o.type = 'P'  
        and o2.type = 'P'
        and o.id = @PROC_ID

    OPEN CURS
    FETCH CURS INTO @CURR_NAME, @CURR_ID

    WHILE (@@SQLSTATUS <> 2)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @PATH_OUT = @PATH + @CURR_NAME + '/'

        select @ROW_COUNT = COUNT(1)
        from sysdepends d
            inner join sysobjects o
            on d.id = o.id
            inner join sysobjects o2
            on d.depid = o2.id
        where o.type = 'P'  
            and o2.type = 'P'
            and o.id = @CURR_ID

        IF (@ROW_COUNT > 0)
            EXEC PROC_DEP_REC @CURR_ID, @PATH_OUT OUTPUT
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                IF (RIGHT(@PATH_OUT, 1) = '/')
                    SELECT @PATH_OUT = LEFT(@PATH_OUT, LEN(@PATH_OUT) - 1)

                INSERT INTO PROC_HIERARCHY VALUES (@PATH_OUT)
            END

        FETCH CURS INTO @CURR_NAME, @CURR_ID
    END

    CLOSE CURS
    DEALLOCATE CURS

    IF (RIGHT(@PATH_OUT, 1) = '/')
        SELECT @PATH = SUBSTRING(@PATH_OUT, 1, LEN(@PATH_OUT) - CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@PATH_OUT))) 
END

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.PROC_DEP
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @CURR_ID        INTEGER
    DECLARE @CURR_NAME      VARCHAR(40)
    DECLARE @PATH           VARCHAR(4000)

    DECLARE CURS CURSOR FOR
    select distinct o.name, o.id
    from sysdepends d
        inner join sysobjects o
        on d.id = o.id
        inner join sysobjects o2
        on d.depid = o2.id
    where o.type = 'P'  
        and o2.type = 'P'

    OPEN CURS
    FETCH CURS INTO @CURR_NAME, @CURR_ID

    WHILE (@@SQLSTATUS <> 2)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @PATH = @CURR_NAME + '/'
        EXEC PROC_DEP_REC @CURR_ID, @PATH OUTPUT

        FETCH CURS INTO @CURR_NAME, @CURR_ID
    END

    CLOSE CURS
    DEALLOCATE CURS

    SELECT DISTINCT * 
    FROM PROC_HIERARCHY 
    ORDER BY PROC_PATH

END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

What about the queries in sp_depends itself?
Go to the $SYBASE/ASE-X_Y/scripts directory and find the installmaster file (or instmstr on WIndows) and look for sp_depends. 
Then you just need to format the output a bit differently, for exmaple by running a cursor loop over the final result set.

Comment: by the way I couldnt find script directory `C:\sybase\ASE-15_0`

Comment: That probably means your installation directory is somewhere else. It does not have to be c:\sybase. On windows, it is indicated by %SYBASE%